# Use of undeclared type 'QBSessionParameters'

Tags: swift, quickblox

I am New for Swift, In my App I use the Quickblox latest version SDK for Chat but I have some error in my code and I have unable to fix it please help me for fix the error.

Here I post the code what i am tried.

```
var parameters: QBSessionParameters = QBSessionParameters() //----> Error in this line
                        parameters.userLogin = CommonClass.prefixStr()
                        parameters.userPassword = CommonClass.prefixStr()
```

Comment: try < var parameters = QBSessionParameters() > and check what is the error ?

Comment: No It is not working @sourav

Comment: so what is the error now ?

Comment: This time it shows like--> Use of unresolved identifier 'QBSessionParameters'

Comment: can you send the code so i can check .

Comment: does it redirect to QBSessionParameters file when you cmd+click on the 'QBSessionParameters'  , as i didn't find the QBSessionParameters in the current Framework headers. ,may be in the updated version they have removed that